# How to restrict a user from editing an Excel workbook in a network shared folder when it is being edited (open) by another user?

Tags: excel, vba

Can it be done through VBA, since I have some VBA code running, maybe I can add into it, or it's just a simple setting in a menu that I didn't realize? Pretty new to Excel, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The function `Application.UserName` will return you a string with the name of the user so you can use it on your VBA code on something like `If Application.UserName = "Name Of The User" then`.

Comment: learnt something new today! thanks for the tip, will give it a go